# filter tweets by location using client tweepy latest version

Tags: python, tweets

```
import tweepy as tw

client = tw.Client(bearer_token='')
```

I want to filter the tweet data using a location search query that I found from twitters client API docs.

I tried using `bounding_box` as a filter location but it just outputs an error every time I use it `There were errors processing your request: no viable alternative at input '119.19,4.94,127.31,19.38'`

```
query = 'crypto -is:retweet bounding_box:[119.19,4.94,127.31,19.38]'

for tweet in tw.Paginator(client.search_recent_tweets, query=query, 
tweet_fields=[ 'created_at'], max_results=100).flatten(limit=1000):

    print(tweet.text, tweet.created_at)
```

is there a possible way of filtering the tweet data by location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace commas with spaces:

```
query = 'crypto -is:retweet bounding_box:[119.19 4.94 127.31 19.38]'
```

..as is stated in Twitter API [docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query):

> bounding_box:[west_long south_lat east_long north_lat]

> Example: bounding_box:[-105.301758 39.964069 -105.178505 40.09455]

> Rule arguments are contained within brackets, space delimited.